# How to best communicate to my python program from an android phone?

Tags: android, python, communication

I currently have a python program running on a raspberry pi that is working as a security camera that uploads to dropbox. Currently my only way of starting the program is to log into my Pi with vnc and run the program in the terminal. Then to turn it off I have to view it again through vnc and kill the program. There are also a few other things like clearing out my capture cache that I have to do through SSH, requiring me to log in every time and run a different program.

What is the most straight forward method to communicate to my program from an android phone? I am looking for something that I can just open and tap a button rather than logging into an SSH session or VNC session.